# Nearest Neighbors on a regular grid

Tags: algorithm, matrix, geometry, nearest-neighbor

There are many algorithms, like KD-Trees, for finding the nearest neighbor among a set of candidate points, of any given point.
If all of my points (including the candidate points) are on a regular grid, it seems to me that there should be a shortcut algorithm for identifying the nearest neighbor - but I cannot seem to find any.

Is there such an algorithm? - and if yes, what is it? (pseudocode, code or a reference would all be useful answers).

Comment: Can you make the question a bit more precise so that the answer isn't "yes"?

Comment: @mkrieger1 that does not answer my question - as I requested an algorithm that shortcut the KDTree approach by leveragiong the regular grid nature of the position of the points. Yours does neither.

Comment: If the grid pattern is regular and the points are ordered in a know fashion, say top left to bottom right, then the simplest solution would be the row above and below and left and right of the candidate location (with edge effects to dropping one or more of those considerations)

Comment: That's what I meant by making the question more precise. What exactly do you define as "shortcut"?

Comment: If most grid cell contain a (one) point, then NaN's algorithm is probably best. If your dataset is large and more 'sparse' you may want to use something different, such as an R-Tree or STR-Tree. Especially STR-Trees (sort-tile-recurse R-Trees) will internally something similarilar to a (hierarchy of) grid(s). I also found them regularly more efficient than kd-trees for pretty much any type of operation except insertion.